# Testing that an $interval gets fired 3 times in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS service that looks like this (I've removed the unrelevant code):

```
myApp.factory('myService', ['$interval', function ($interval) {
  return {
    startWatch: function(onSuccess) {
      var watcher = $interval(onSuccess, 250);
      return watcher;
    },

    stopWatch: function(watcher) {
      $interval.cancel(watcher);
    }
  };
}]);
```

To test this service, I have the following:

```
describe('myApp', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        module('myApp');
    });

    describe('myService', function () {
        var myService = null;
        beforeEach(inject(function (myService) {
            myService = myService;
        }));

        it('should run successfully 3 times', function() {
          var count = 0;

          var w = myService.startWatch(function() {
            count = count + 1;
            console.log('fired ' + count + ' times.');
          });
        });
    });
});
```

When the test gets ran, it just races through it one time. I do not understand how to actually test 1. the interval piece 2. the number of times it gets fired. There will be information in the service that changes over time. I want to test that the information is behaving as expected. For that reason, I'm trying to test a number of things over time. How do I do this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't see any code that limit the interval to fire only 3 times. Is it somewhere that you omitted?

Comment: do you reference angular mock in your test? http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular-mocks.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [$interval.flush(millis)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$interval#flush):

```
describe('myApp', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        module('myApp');
    });

    describe('myService', function () {
        var myService = null;
        var $interval = null;
        beforeEach(inject(function (myService) {
            myService = myService;
            $interval = _$interval_;
        }));

        it('should run successfully 3 times', function() {
          var count = 0;

          var w = myService.startWatch(function() {
            count = count + 1;
          });

          $interval.flush(751); // greater than 250 * 3
          expect(count).toEqual(3);
        });
    });
});
```

Remember to reference angular mock to your test: http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular-mocks.js .The version should be the same with your angular version.